# Question about the proof of the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem in "Partial Differential equations" by C. Evans.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Im trying to understand the proof of the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem in C. Evans book "Partial Differential equations", that is, theorem 1 in section 5.7. After proving that $u_m^\epsilon \rightarrow u_m$ in $L^q(V)$ he proves that $\{u_m^\epsilon\}_{m \geq 1}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous for fixed $\epsilon > 0$. He then estimates $\lvert u_m^\epsilon(x)\rvert$ which obviously proves that $\{u_m^\epsilon\}_{m \geq 1}$ is uniformly bounded, but then he estimates $\lvert Du_m^\epsilon(x)\lvert$, which is the euclidean norm of the gradient vector, and claims that this shows uniform equicontinuity, without further explanation. My question is how does uniform equicontinuity follows from these two estimates?

Comment: That's a classical fact. A uniformly bounded derivative implies equicontinuity, which is also intuitively clear if you think about it. The point is that a sequence of functions with uniformly bounded derivative has a common Lipschitz constant, so in particular it is uniformly equicontinuous.